# How to have an image zoom in and out automatically using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to have an image zoom in and out automatically using CSS? I want this animation to be continuous.

I found a link where there is a code to zoom in and out a background image. 
[How to have an image zoom in and out automatically in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196704/how-to-have-an-image-zoom-in-and-out-automatically-in-the-background)

But I want a simple image (no background image) that automatically zoom in and out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this using `transform: scale()`

```css
img {
  animation: zoom 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1900/1900/?random">
```